# Is it possible to edit the installed unmanaged package?

Tags: unmanaged-package

Can we edit the installed unmanaged package ? I need to enhanced the trigger that is the part of the unmanaged package.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You are able to edit all of the components that are part of an unmanaged package.

From the [Overview of Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm&language=en_US) page.

> ### Unmanaged packages
>
> Unmanaged packages are typically used to distribute open-source projects or application templates to provide developers with the basic building blocks for an application. **Once the components are installed from an unmanaged package, the components can be edited in the organization they are installed in.** The developer who created and uploaded the unmanaged package has no control over the installed components, and can't change or upgrade them. Unmanaged packages should not be used to migrate components from a sandbox to production organization. Instead, use Change Sets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can edit code in an unmanaged package

You may have to modify test methods depending on your updates

Comment: I think sunil was asking about unmanaged package

Comment: @Prady If you modify the code in an unmanaged package, you will also need to update the test classes to cover any new code you've written in the classes or triggers you've modified. Code is code and its considered YOUR code.

Comment: @crmprogdev Erics original answer was referring to managed package and he changed it after i dropped the comment :)

Comment: Apologies. Didn't notice that it had been edited after your comments.